# ssh to remote server inside remote server using jsch(jump server to dev machine)

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have two machines dev server and log server which has logs stored, I want to first ssh to dev server and then from there i want to do ssh to log server to execute some script.
Below is the code I tried using jsch :

Get jschSession:

```
private Session getSSHSession(String user,String host,String password) {
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    Session session = null;
    try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return session;
}
```

Execute a command

```
private String execute(Session session, String cmd) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();
        BufferedReader br  =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
        String msg = null;
        while ((msg = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(msg);
        }
        System.out.println("------------msg: -----------"+sb.toString());
        while(true){
            System.out.println("channel.getExitStatus(): "+channel.getExitStatus());
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            if(channel.getExitStatus()==0) {
                System.out.println("script executed successfully..........");
            }
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

call the execute

```
public String audit(AuditRequest request) {
    Session session = getSSHSession(user,host,password);
    String cmd = "ssh user@server; cd /mmt/test;ls -ltr";
    String result = execute(session,cmd);
    System.out.println("cmd1: "+cmd+"  result: -------------"+result);
    return result;
}
```

So basically I am first connecting to dev server and then using its session I am trying to execute the ssh command to connect to log server. 
By the posted code I am able to connect to my dev machine but from there not able to do ssh to log machine.

If i remove `((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);` below is the error I am getting:

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.`

And ifI put the setPty for pseudo terminal , it's stucking in `channel.connect();`

Read multiple posts/questions lots of people mentioned using channel.setPty(true) But that doesn't seems to work

Could anyone help me to know what is going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: For the "jump", use port forwarding instead of running `ssh`.